# Why PHP output fails?

Tags: php, browser, output

I was writing php script using pear mail queue in which I add emails and template of email in mail queue. After all processing, script display numbers of emails added to queue and number of  emails rejected and a progress bar. Now when I send around 700-800 mails to queue output renders perfectly but when number of mails are around 2000-2500 output doesn't render. I thought that, there maybe no output for long time, because script takes around 2-3 minutes while adding 2500 to queue, I echo `div` with `display:none` in each iteration of loop, now output render perfectly. Is it because what I am thinking or is this related to something else. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a timeout setting, which is typically set by default to around 30 seconds. If the program takes longer than that to run, it will throw a timeout error and stop running.

It does not matter whether you have been sending output to the browser or not; if the timeout limit is reached, the program will stop.

This 30 seconds value can be adjusted in a number of ways.

You can [set it in the `php.ini` file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time), or adjust it [directly in your program](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) while the program is running.

Please note that some web hosts may prevent you from changing the timeout. If you have trouble changing it, you may need to talk to your hosting company.

Comment: Time limit setting is there in script, and script is not throwing a timeout error neither it stop running.